# Cant cast float to int if object

Tags: c#, casting

This code runs fine

```
float ff = 5.5f;
int fd = (int) ff;

Console.Write(fd);
```

Where as this code doesnt

```
float ff = 5.5f;
object jf = ff;
int fd = (int) jf;

Console.Write(fd);
```

What rule in the runner causes this to happen?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can cast a float to an int, but you can't cast a *boxed* float to an int - you have to unbox it first.

```
int fd = (int)(float)jf;
```

Read Eric Lippert's post [Representation and Identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

```
float ff = 5.5f; 
object jf = ff;
int fd = (int) jf;
```

here when you box from float to object , actual type which jf is float and you are unboxing an boxed float directly to int which is not accepted by the runtime.

so you need to first unboxed to float and then cast once again to int.