# Double-casting required to convert from int as object to float

Tags: c#, object, casting, boxing

Here's a weird one I ran into.  I've got a function that returns an `object`.  In a particular case, I know for sure that object is an `int`, but another function calling this function requires a `float`.  The only way I could get this to work was the following:

```
private object parser(string expr) {...}

private float parseFloat(string expr)
{
    ...
    object result = parser(expr);
    if (result is int)
        return (float)(int)result;
    else
        return (float)result;
}
```

Without that type-check, I couldn't get it to work at all, even though I knew the result of the parser function in this case was an `int`.  (You could see it in the debugger.)  I'd prefer the line to go simply:

```
private float parseFloat(string expr)
{
    ...
    return (float)parser(expr);
}
```

(Type checking is done beforehand, and `parseFloat` should never be called with an expression that will not evaluate to a `float` or `int`.)  Is there some reason why it's necessary to double-cast this variable?  I obviously don't want to double-cast it in all cases, because if the return from `parser` *was* a `float`, it would truncate it to `int` first and we don't want that.  (And yes, I tried replacing `float` and `int` with `Single` and `Int32`, etc.  Didn't make any difference.)

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352697/cant-cast-float-to-int-if-object), but it depends on knowing the type in advance, and the only solution it offers is this double-casting trick, which in my case would truncate `float`s unless I do a type-check first, which also requires an additional local variable to hold the result.  Is there any way to avoid that extra step?

Comment: Why don't you provide  a `ParseFloat` if you know for sure that it's one?

Comment: That's what the ... is for.  The expression passed to `ParseFloat` is either a float literal (which is handled in the ... code), or a function which returns a float.  The `parser`'s job is to interpret such functions (which may in fact be several nested functions).

Comment: This is a frequently asked question. I answered it in 2009, here: http://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/

Comment: @EricLippert Nice article, explains it pretty well.  Doesn't make it any less annoying, but at least there's a good reason why this doesn't work the way you'd expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you unbox a value type that has been put into an `object` box, you must use the correct cast. The conversion from one numeric type to another is an extra cast that comes after the unboxing.

In your case, however, the second cast is really implicit, so you could simplify a little bit to:

```
if (result is int)
    return (int)result;
else
    return (float)result;
```

Why do you have boxed value types in the first place? If you don't know what type is boxed, to unbox you will normally have to check with `is` the way you do.

Note, however, that with (`IConvertible`) types like these built-in numeric types, you can also use the `Convert` class, so:

```
return Convert.ToSingle(result);
```

It looks more pretty, but I don't think it's faster. It will probably do the same kind of type checking.

If the `parser` gives only numeric types, and if for some reason you insist on boxing these value types, you might as well box them to `IConvertible`, so that involves changing the return type like this:

```
private IConvertible parser(string expr) {...}
```

Then your code could go so:

```
IConvertible result = parser(expr);  // it's some number boxed in an IConvertible reference type
return result.ToSingle(null);  // instance method in IConvertible
```

Comment: An improvement - still requires a temporary variable and a type-check though.  Is there really no way around that?  Only other thing I can think of is reducing it to a `?:` instead of the `if`\ `else`, but still doesn't save the extra step.

Comment: Okay, the `Convert.Tosingle` trick in your edit does solve the problem, though it'd be difficult at this time to do a performance-comparison between the two.  Seems like regular casting should be smart enough to unbox and rebox the result as needed?  At least for the built-in types anyhow.

Comment: In regards to your last edit - no, the `parser` can return quite a few non-numeric types, which is why it returns `object`.  It also handles `bool`s, `string`s, a custom Vector4 class, and `List`s of all of the above.  Some script functions even have a `void` return (though under the hood it just returns `null`).  Each type has its own `Parse` function like `ParseFloat` above.  It's far too much code to post here, I just simplified it to show the problem.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Well, this is the way the rules of C# were made, and for a good reason, I think. Conversion from `int` to `float` is a binary change of representation (one is a two's complement integer representation, the other is an IEEE floating-point representation). The C# compiler will not know if it has to emit both an unboxing conversion and a numeric conversion. The only other option I see (other than the ideas from my answer), is to use `dynamic`. If `r` is of type `dynamic`, the expression `(float)r` will work, and it will not be decided until runtime what conversion is implied.

Comment: Thanks - I went with `return Convert.ToSingle(parser(expr));`  This avoids creating a temporary variable and a type-check, even if the `Convert` class is doing the same thing under the hood.  The `dynamic` solution also seems to work, but it's an extra line because a variable has to be created.  Not sure which is better performance-wise, I may have to test on a larger scale to see any difference.